# SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() does not throw SqlException when deadlocked

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

We're using C# `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` to issue SQL Server stored procedure and SQL requests inside a transaction.

When the connection is chosen as a deadlock victim, `ExecuteReader()` does NOT throw `SqlException` with 1205 deadlock code for some commands but DOES for others.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *If a transaction is deadlocked, an exception may not be thrown until Read is called.*

Considering that we use `SqlCommand` object encapsulated inside our own database request framework, is there a way to always guarantee that the exception is thrown when a deadlock occurs?

We're using .Net 4.5, SQL Server 2008 R2, Visual Studio 2012

Here is a simplified version of our database access framework code:

```
SqlDataReader DoWork( string sql ) {
    ...
    cmd = new SqlCommand( sql );
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;

    try {
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader( CommandBehavior.Default ); 
    } catch (SqlException sqle) {
        // Log the error, throw a custom exception, etc.
        // if (sqle.ErrorCode == 1205) ...
        ...
        if (rdr != null) {
            rdr.Close();
            rdr = null;
        }
    }
    // All is well, so just return to caller to consume the result set
    return rdr;
}

...

main() {
    ...
    SqlDataReader result = DoWork( "select ...";

    if (result.HasRows) { // Check there is data to read...
        while (result.Read()) {
            ...
        }
    result.Close();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code please to enable us to help

Comment: or, option 2 -- Get rid of the deadlocks.

Comment: try the answer in this question here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146171/how-to-recover-from-deadlock-exception-during-sqldatareader-read

Comment: @Hogan That's an answer for THIS deadlock, but other ones can come up sometimes. Until you're able to fix the root cause of a new deadlock situation, that's not helpful.

Comment: @Hogan or to take this a step further, why have ANY error handling in any code?  Why not just write error-proof code?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you are doing this:

```
if (result.HasRows)
```

This is not necessary and it prevents the deadlock from appearing:

> If a transaction is deadlocked, an exception may not be thrown until Read is called.

Delete that `if`. It's a common anti pattern. It's often introduced by people who copy sample code without really understanding what it does.

This in your `catch` is also an anti pattern:

```
    if (rdr != null) {
        rdr.Close();
        rdr = null;
    }
```

Just use `using`.

Comment: the code posted is just an over-simplified version of what there is in our framework.   `using` is not an option because we pass SqlDataReader objects around. A more fundamental question is about the utility of HasRows vs omitting it completely. Copying and pasting of sample code without understanding is not quite the case here...

Comment: OK, maybe this answer is worded too strictly. I'll keep it that way, though.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code from that link, Stack wouldnt allow it as an answer

```
function DoWork() {
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(...)) {
cmd = new SqlCommand("select ...");
using (DataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
    while(rdr.Read()) {
      ... process each record
    }
 }
  scope.Complete ();
 }
}
```

Comment: We were following MS-recommended pattern of first checking if the data reader has rows available *before* using Read(). Of course we can completely eliminate HasRows altogether if there are any drawbacks or performance-related issues.
(see sample pseudo-code in the updated question)

Comment: @alexg Read() returns false if there are no more rows to read. So while (rdr.Read()) will not iterate if there are no rows to read.